# Como colocar um scroll dentro do tabHost (asbas) no Android?

Tags: android

Eu tenho  um código que cria abas na tela conforme a necessidade, o problema é que quando crio muitas abas elas ficam "espremidas" na tela e corta o resto que tem nas abas. Estou fazendo isso tudo via Java, sem usar xml então não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar o meu scroll, alguém sabe como posso fazer isso? Agradeço desde já.

Meu código resumido:

***Minha classe herda de uma TabActivity*** não estou usando `hs = new HorizontalScrollView(this);` na primeira linha dentro do código. Tentei usar mais não deu certo.

```
public void adicionaAbas(String texto) {

    hs = new HorizontalScrollView(this);

    TabHost th = getTabHost();

    th.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    TabSpec ts = th.newTabSpec(texto);
    // nome da aba
    ts.setIndicator(texto);


    th.addTab(ts);

    setContentView(th);
}
```

Comment: Como assim elas ficam "espremidas"? todas ficam no canto esquerdo da tela? Poderia postar uma imagem? Com mais detalhes eu posso lhe ajudar.

Comment: Por exemplo, minha tela tem 9cm de largura, quando são 3 abas, cada uma ocupa 3cm, mas de forem 18 abas, cada uma vai ocupar 0,5cm e vai "cortar" o texto da aba. com o scroll, elas ficariam com o tamanho necessário para aparecer o texto. Da para fazer isso fácil em xml, o problema é que não estou conseguindo fazer cia código.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você deva ajustar o tamanho da ScrollView.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
hs.setLayoutParams(params);
```